# LWC - Don't get the Data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, list, data

With this code, I want to get the last stock value of my record respecting the condition and transfer the value in ‰ and take only the two digits after the decimal point.

The problem I have is that I get the data but I find myself in the catch message directly and also I have no idea how to retrieve the two digits after the comma.

I get the same problem and I get this error Error stock :

```
{"status":500,"body": {"exceptionType":"System.ListException","isUserDefinedException": false,"message":"List index out of bounds: 0","stackTrace": "Class.stock.getstock: line 36, column 1"},"headers":{}}  The line 36 is the return in apex class :           return ob1[0].Stock__c ;
```

Any help please

==> Apex Class

```
 @AuraEnabled
      public static Double  getstock(Id accId){
        
        list<Obj__c> ob1 = [SELECT Id,Stock__c FROM Obj__c
        WHERE Acc__c  =:accId order by CreatedDate desc];
  
          return ob1[0].Stock__c ;
      }
```

==> JS

```
connectedCallback() {
    getstock({ acctId : this.recordId }).then(data => {
        if (data)
      //this console give me the correct data 
        console.log('data in if est '+data);
            {
                if ((data.Stock__c) < 10000 || (data.Stock__c) > -10000) {
                   console.log('condition1 ');
                   this.stockt = data.Stock__c/10;
                   // In this ligne I don't get the value even if I get the data 
                   console.log('teste stock1 '+this.stockt);
                    this.showGreen= true;
                } else {
                    console.log('condition2 ');
                    this.stockt= data.Stock__c/10;
                    console.log('teste stock2'+this.stockt);
                    this.showRed= true;
                }
            }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(' error est '+this.stockt);
        console.log('Error stock : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already returning the `Stock__c` field value from Apex, the `data` in JavaScript `.then(data)` will already have that value.

Replace `data.Stock__c` with `data`.

---

In the Apex method, if no records are returned in the SOQL query then `ob1[0]` will throw *List index out of bounds* error.

To avoid this, check if the List has records after the SOQL statement executes. If not use a return statement.

```js
@AuraEnabled
public static Double getstock(Id accId){
    List<Obj__c> ob1 = [SELECT Id,Stock__c FROM Obj__c
    WHERE Acc__c  =:accId order by CreatedDate desc LIMIT 1];

    if(ob1.isEmpty()){
     return null;
    }
    return ob1[0].Stock__c ;
}
```

---

To get the 2 digits after the decimal use below logic:

```js
let value = (data % 1).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: even if I replace the  data.Stock__c with data I get the same problem and I get this error `Error stock : {"status":500,"body":
{"exceptionType":"System.ListException","isUserDefinedException":
false,"message":"List index out of bounds: 0","stackTrace":
"Class.stock.getstock: line 36, column 1"},"headers":{}}

The line 36 is the return in apex class :           return ob1[0].Stock__c ; `

Comment: I updated my question with the error

Comment: I added your code and I worked for me , thank you , Do you have any idea how to get just the 2 numbers after the comma please

Comment: What is the value that you need to format? Provide the details in the question

Comment: I need to format the value of Stock__c , I want it to be in ‰ , that why I used `data/10 ` and that give me just 2 number after the comma

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev - updated the answer for the decimal points logic

Comment: thank you for your help , it worked for me and the problem is resolved